# Microsoft VS Error When Loading C# Project

Tags: visual-studio

any time I load my project in VS it throws the following error. I believe it has to do with the Microsoft .NET files for VS. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated as I feel I have tried everything.

`2023-10-22 10:17:46.523 [info] Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Server.BuildHost, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

I have tried reinstalling VS and Reinstalling the .Net need for VS.

Comment: Ok I did a complete fresh install and the previous error has been resolved although now i am getting the following error. I know I need to install .Net Runtime 6.0 although I am confused as to which version I need. Do I need 6.0 Desktop or Console and would i need the x84 version or the x64 version. I have put the error below.

Comment: 2023-10-22 16:37:19.310 [info] It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.12 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86